On finding solution to linear system with norm of independent variable
Let's consider the solution to a well-behaved linear system of equation: $y + Ax + \rho x = 0 \implies x = -(A + \rho I)^{-1}y$.
For now, let's consider the simplest case that $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$.
If I modify the equation to $y + Ax + \rho x ||x||  = 0$, all I can do is write like this $x = -(A + \rho ||x|| I)^{-1}y$. But let's say that this is not an iteration algorithm and I want to find the exact solution (so I can't take $||x||$ from the previous iteration). Is it possible to separate the variable $x$ and write down an exact solution (or an approximate one)?
